# How to turn a list into many strings - Python

Tags: string, list, split, count

I was wondering if I have a list such as ['This is my list'], how can I split it into 4 strings such that I can count them?

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using Python!

Comment: It depends on which language you are using! For example, in Python, you can use .split(' ') which splits the string using space as separator.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
l=['This is my list']
ans = [ i.split() for i in l ]
print ans[0]
```